# Using multiple runners in one gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to run CI pipline with 2 jobs:

1. job will boot up a docker image with docker-runner and run test inside docker
2. will run under ssh runner and pull code on a remote server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible. You need to:

1. Register two *GitLab Runners* with needed *executor* (`docker` and `shell`), each witch different tag (or, at least one of them with a build tag).
2. Declare a specific *tag* for given *job* in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, .

**Shell runner registration:**

```
[root@jsc00mca ~]# gitlab-runner register
Running in system-mode.                            

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
https://example.com/
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
1a2b3c
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[jsc00mca.example.com]: my-shell-runner
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
shell
Whether to run untagged builds [true/false]:
[false]: 
Whether to lock the Runner to current project [true/false]:
[true]:
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=ajgHxcNz
Please enter the executor: virtualbox, docker+machine, kubernetes, docker, shell, ssh, docker-ssh+machine, docker-ssh, parallels:
shell
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

**Docker runner registration:**

```
[root@jsc00mca ~]# gitlab-runner register
Running in system-mode.                            

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
https://example.com/
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
1a2b3c
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[jsc00mca.example.com]: my-docker-runner
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
docker
Whether to run untagged builds [true/false]:
[false]: 
Whether to lock the Runner to current project [true/false]:
[true]:
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=ajgHxcNz
Please enter the executor: virtualbox, docker+machine, kubernetes, docker, shell, ssh, docker-ssh+machine, docker-ssh, parallels:
docker
Please enter the default Docker image (e.g. ruby:2.1):
alpine:latest
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yml
buildWithShell:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - shell
  script:
  - echo 'Building with the shell executor...'

buildWithDocker:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: build
  tags:
  - docker
  script:
  - echo 'Building with the docker executor...'
```

Comment: Do these two runners share the same `config.toml` file?

Comment: Yes, the same config file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can trigger different/mixed runners from a single gitlab-ci pipeline.

First you should register a shell runner on the target host and give it a tag (truncated):

```
$ gitlab-runner register
...

Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
my_shell_runner
...
Please enter the executor: virtualbox, docker+machine, docker-ssh+machine, docker, docker-ssh, parallels, shell, ssh:
shell
```

Within your gitlab-ci.yaml something like this should work.
The 'test' job runs your test command in a docker container based on the image NAME_OF_IMAGE.

If that succeeds, the 'deploy' job chooses your shell runner based on the tag 'my_shell_runner' and will execute all commands within the script tag on the runner's host (truncated):

```
 test:
   stage: test
   services:
     - docker:dind
   tags:
     - docker-executor
   script:
     - docker run --rm NAME_OF_IMAGE sh -c "TEST_COMMAND_TO_RUN"

 deploy:
   stage: deploy
   tags:
     - my_shell_runner
   script:
     - COMMAND_TO_RUN
     - COMMAND_TO_RUN
     - COMMAND_TO_RUN
```